# Validating the textbox in c#.net

Tags: c#

hi i want to set my text box only with the alphabets i have tried the following code, it's working fine for the keyboard keys.but if i press the numpad key numbers it is accepting numbers can anyone please help me, much appreciated thanks.

```
bool isvalid = true;

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyValue <65 || e.KeyValue > 90) && (e.KeyValue<97||e.KeyValue>122) e.KeyValue != 8))
        {
            isvalid = false;
            MessageBox.Show("only alphabets");

        }
        else
        {
            isvalid = true;

        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isvalid == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Regex.IsMatch` property.

**Can Use Following Code:**

```
private void txtAlphaOnly_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("^[a-zA-Z]", txtAlphaOnly.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Alphabets Only Allowed");            
    }
}
```

**MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx

Hope Its helpful.

Comment: this is much better than validation on keypress because it allows copying&pasting etc..

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace windowsDemo
{
    public partial class textbox1 : Form
    {
        public textbox1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("^[a-zA-Z]",textBox2.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Alphabets Only Allowed");
            }
        }
    }
}   I tried the following code as you said but it still accepting both numbers and keypad numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In the KeyDown event what you will get on e.KeyValue is code of key on keyboard not characters, See [Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx). This condition is true for A-Z and a-z.

```
 (e.KeyValue >= Keys.A && e.KeyValue <= Keys.Z)
```